# WhatsApp like calling notification in android even if app is killed

Tags: android

I am currently working in an android project.Can anyone please explain me how WhatsApp handles to show the calling notification screen even if the app is killed and phone is locked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I worked on a project that had a similar task. I achieved this with the help of push notifications. WhatsApp and other major apps also achieve this via push notification service.

- Create a service which would listen for the push notifications
- in `onMessageReceived` don't show a notification rather launch the activity you would like to show. ex: incoming call screen
- Make sure this activity your showing has permission to show on top of the lock screen. this can be done by
  `<activity
      android:name=".yourActivityName"
      android:showOnLockScreen="true"
      android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >`

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: Hope it will work even if the app is not running

Comment: Yes it work even when the app is killed off and not running

Comment: I tried with the solution you suggested. It works fine only when the app is in foreground.When the app is in background,or killed the app is not being launched.Just push notification is received in the notification bar

Comment: you need to launch your activity in the `onMessageReceived` from your pushnotificationservice

Comment: Thank you it worked

Comment: But it does not wok when the phone is locked. I added  android:showOnLockScreen="true"

Comment: glad it worked can you mark the answer as correct

Comment: @Sobinscott to make it work when the phone is locked you need to give the activity permission to run over lock screen

Comment: Thank you.It works.I am listing the steps I have done.

Comment: @MukeshSolanki,  Please what exact permission is required to run over lock screen?

Comment: Is there any way to hide incoming call view and navigate around the app. and there can be an indicator on all pages and tapping on that it can bring back the incoming call view (Ongoing callview) like whatsApp?