# Android 10 Incoming call notification like whats app when we are in another app

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, whatsapp

Once we received FCM push notification message in android 10 background start activities restricted. Need a solution like WhatsApp and Skype notification incoming call when we are in another app.

[image]

```
int NOTIFICATIONID = 1234;
       // Uri sound =  RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.capv_callingtone);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();
            String CHANNEL_ID = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.concat("_notification_id");
            String CHANNEL_NAME = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.concat("_notification_name");
            assert notificationManager != null;

            NotificationChannel mChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID);
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                mChannel.setSound(sound, audioAttributes);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
            in.setClass(CapVFirebaseMessagingService.this, DashBoardActivity.class);
            in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            in.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATIONID);
            Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
            buttonIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATIONID);
            buttonIntent.putExtra(CapV.MESSAGE_TYPE,in.getSerializableExtra(CapV.MESSAGE_TYPE));
            Log.d("Audiotask",""+in.getSerializableExtra(CapV.MESSAGE_TYPE));
            PendingIntent dismissIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, buttonIntent, 0);
            SharedPreferences localPrefs = getSharedPreferences(LOCAL_PREFERENCES,MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(LOCAL_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("Fragment_created",true).commit();
            editor.putBoolean("Incoming_call",true).commit();
            // The PendingIntent to launch activity.
            PendingIntent activityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    in, 0);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);

            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setContentTitle(("Incoming Call"))
                    .setContentText("Group")
                    .setDefaults(0)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.answer, getString(R.string.answer),
                            activityPendingIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.reject, getString(R.string.reject),
                            dismissIntent)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setSound(sound)
                    .setOngoing(true);
            android.app.Notification notification = builder.build();
            notificationManager.notify(1234, notification);
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

below code for foreground service and a time-sensitive notification.

startForeground(1234, getNotification(incomingCallIntent));

```
private android.app.Notification getNotification(Intent in) {



    in.putExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION, true);

   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);

    // Set the Channel ID for Android O.
        //builder.setChannelId("115"); // Channel ID

   return builder.build();


}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open activity (incoming voip call) in Android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58819246/how-to-open-activity-incoming-voip-call-in-android-10)

Comment: Can you any one help me this issue.

Comment: Did you get any solution for that I am looking for same

Comment: You got any solution?

Comment: did you found any solution for this ?

Comment: this you found the solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792777/whatsapp-like-calling-notification-in-android-even-if-app-is-killed/49793287

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792777/whatsapp-like-calling-notification-in-android-even-if-app-is-killed/49793287

Answer (score 19):

I find a solution for that. You need to create a foreground service for that.
This will also help you to show the ringing dialer on the lock screen also. In this code, I add ringtone and vibration.

**CallNotificationService**

```
public class HeadsUpNotificationService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener  {
private String CHANNEL_ID = AppController.getInstance().getContext().getString(R.string.app_name)+"CallChannel";
private String CHANNEL_NAME = AppController.getInstance().getContext().getString(R.string.app_name)+"Call Channel";MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Vibrator mvibrator;
AudioManager audioManager;
AudioAttributes  playbackAttributes;
private Handler handler;
AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener;
private boolean status = false;
private boolean vstatus = false;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Bundle data = null;
    String name="",callType="";
    int NOTIFICATION_ID=120;try {
        audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        if (audioManager != null) {
            switch (audioManager.getRingerMode()) {
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                    status = true;
                    break;
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                    status = false;
                    break;
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                    status = false;
                    vstatus=true;
                    Log.e("Service!!", "vibrate mode");
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (status) {
            Runnable delayedStopRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    releaseMediaPlayer();
                }
            };

            afChangeListener =  new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
               public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                   if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
                       // Permanent loss of audio focus
                       // Pause playback immediately
                       //mediaController.getTransportControls().pause();
                       if (mediaPlayer!=null) {
                           if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                               mediaPlayer.pause();
                           }
                       }
                       // Wait 30 seconds before stopping playback
                       handler.postDelayed(delayedStopRunnable,
                               TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30));
                   }
                   else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) {
                       // Pause playback
                   } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) {
                       // Lower the volume, keep playing
                   } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
                       // Your app has been granted audio focus again
                       // Raise volume to normal, restart playback if necessary
                   }
               }
           };
             KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);


            mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            //mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                 handler = new Handler();


              playbackAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .build();

                AudioFocusRequest focusRequest = new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT)
                        .setAudioAttributes(playbackAttributes)
                        .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
                        .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(afChangeListener, handler)
                        .build();
                int res = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(focusRequest);
                if (res == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                      if(!keyguardManager.isDeviceLocked()) {

                          mediaPlayer.start();
                         }

                }
            }else {

                // Request audio focus for playback
                int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener,
                        // Use the music stream.
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        // Request permanent focus.
                        AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

                if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                    if(!keyguardManager.isDeviceLocked()) {
                        // Start playback
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        else if(vstatus){
            mvibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            // Start without a delay
            // Each element then alternates between vibrate, sleep, vibrate, sleep...
            long[] pattern = {0, 250, 200, 250, 150, 150, 75,
                    150, 75, 150};

            // The '-1' here means to vibrate once, as '-1' is out of bounds in the pattern array
            mvibrator.vibrate(pattern,0);
            Log.e("Service!!", "vibrate mode start");

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }         
         
    if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
       
        data = intent.getExtras();
        name =data.getString("inititator");
        if(AppController.getInstance().getCall_type().equalsIgnoreCase(ApplicationRef.Constants.AUDIO_CALL)){
            callType ="Audio";
        }
        else {
            callType ="Video";
        }

    }
    try {
        Intent receiveCallAction = new Intent(AppController.getInstance().getContext(), CallNotificationActionReceiver.class);

        receiveCallAction.putExtra("ConstantApp.CALL_RESPONSE_ACTION_KEY", "ConstantApp.CALL_RECEIVE_ACTION");
        receiveCallAction.putExtra("ACTION_TYPE", "RECEIVE_CALL");
        receiveCallAction.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID",NOTIFICATION_ID);
        receiveCallAction.setAction("RECEIVE_CALL");

        Intent cancelCallAction = new Intent(AppController.getInstance().getContext(), CallNotificationActionReceiver.class);
        cancelCallAction.putExtra("ConstantApp.CALL_RESPONSE_ACTION_KEY", "ConstantApp.CALL_CANCEL_ACTION");
        cancelCallAction.putExtra("ACTION_TYPE", "CANCEL_CALL");
        cancelCallAction.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID",NOTIFICATION_ID);
        cancelCallAction.setAction("CANCEL_CALL");

        Intent callDialogAction = new Intent(AppController.getInstance().getContext(), CallNotificationActionReceiver.class);
        callDialogAction.putExtra("ACTION_TYPE", "DIALOG_CALL");
        callDialogAction.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID",NOTIFICATION_ID);
        callDialogAction.setAction("DIALOG_CALL");

        PendingIntent receiveCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AppController.getInstance().getContext(), 1200, receiveCallAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent cancelCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AppController.getInstance().getContext(), 1201, cancelCallAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent callDialogPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AppController.getInstance().getContext(), 1202, callDialogAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        createChannel();
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = null;
        if (data != null) {
           // Uri ringUri= Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI;
            notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(name)
                    .setContentText("Incoming "+callType+" Call")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_call_icon)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_call_decline, getString(R.string.reject_call), cancelCallPendingIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_call_accept, getString(R.string.answer_call), receiveCallPendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    //.setSound(ringUri)
                    .setFullScreenIntent(callDialogPendingIntent, true);
            
        }

        Notification incomingCallNotification = null;
        if (notificationBuilder != null) {
            incomingCallNotification = notificationBuilder.build();
        }
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, incomingCallNotification);

       
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();// release your media player here audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    releaseVibration();
}

public void createChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        try {
            Uri ringUri= Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setDescription("Call Notifications");
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
           /* channel.setSound(ringUri,
                    new AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                            .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)
                            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION).build());*/
            Objects.requireNonNull(AppController.getInstance().getContext().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class)).createNotificationChannel(channel);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}public void releaseVibration(){
    try {
        if(mvibrator!=null){
            if (mvibrator.hasVibrator()) {
                mvibrator.cancel();
            }
            mvibrator=null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    try {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

}}
```

Service receiver

**CallNotificationActionReceiver**

```
public class CallNotificationActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


Context mContext;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.mContext=context;
    if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
      
        String action ="";
        action=intent.getStringExtra("ACTION_TYPE");

        if (action != null&& !action.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            performClickAction(context, action);
        }

        // Close the notification after the click action is performed.
        Intent iclose = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        context.sendBroadcast(iclose);
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, CallNotificationService.class));

    }


}
private void performClickAction(Context context, String action) {
    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("RECEIVE_CALL")) {

        if (checkAppPermissions()) {                
        Intent intentCallReceive = new Intent(mContext, VideoCallActivity.class);
        intentCallReceive.putExtra("Call", "incoming");
            intentCallReceive.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            mContext.startActivity(intentCallReceive);               
        }
        else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AppController.getInstance().getContext(), VideoCallRingingActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra("CallFrom","call from push");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);                  
            
        }
    }
    else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("DIALOG_CALL")){

                // show ringing activity when phone is locked
                Intent intent = new Intent(AppController.getInstance().getContext(), VideoCallRingingActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }

    else {            
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, CallNotificationService.class));
        Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        context.sendBroadcast(it);
    }
}

private Boolean checkAppPermissions() {
    return hasReadPermissions() && hasWritePermissions() && hasCameraPermissions() && hasAudioPermissions();
}

private boolean hasAudioPermissions() {
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AppController.getInstance().getContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

private boolean hasReadPermissions() {
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AppController.getInstance().getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

private boolean hasWritePermissions() {
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AppController.getInstance().getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
private boolean hasCameraPermissions() {
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AppController.getInstance().getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
}
```

We need to set these two in the manifest inside the application tab

**manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <!-- Incoming call  -->
    <service android:name=".CallNotificationService"/>
    <receiver
        android:name=".CallNotificationActionReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="ConstantApp.CALL_RECEIVE_ACTION" />
            <action android:name="ConstantApp.CALL_CANCEL_ACTION"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

To start the service you need to call it from your firebase notification service.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallNotificationService.class);
                                    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                                    mBundle.putString("inititator", name);
                                    mBundle.putString("call_type",callType);
                                    serviceIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
                                    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(getApplicationContext(), serviceIntent);
}
```

To stop the Notification

```
getApplicationContext().stopService(new Intent(AppController.getInstance().getContext(), HeadsUpNotificationService.class));
                                    Intent istop = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
                                    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(istop);
```

Comment: How to play the ringtone? I'm having trouble with that one

Comment: you need to use media player for that

Comment: Thanks so much for this. But i am facing an issue, service isnt starting when app in background

Comment: you need to start the service from notification service

Comment: When launching the broadcast intent add flags : (FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT, FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND)
also add settings on the launch activity when screen locked  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55901820/5928383
with Manifest permissions to WAKE_LOCK

Comment: Thank you for the reference code... I am able to show the calling notification but my notification banner does not stay continuously for more than 5 secs. Are there any ways to handle this gracefully like what Whatsapp does when you receive an incoming call?

Comment: @Nik follow my code it will stay until we cancel that.

Comment: I'm facing same issue as @Nik... Did you guys find any solution to this issue? I'm using Android 10.

Comment: @MuhammadMehdiRaza what was the issue you facing now?

Comment: @Dinilps you have called .setautocancel() as true, that's why the notification disappears

Comment: @Ibrahim117 for me it's working as expected. my notification will stay until it cancels.

Comment: @Dinilps the media player is not stopping after we call stop service. Can you please help?

Comment: @Sabarinathan release MediaPlayer at service onDestroy() and set as null.. check my code

Comment: Thats a good answer, but i have spotted several issues. 1)Incoming call does not end automatically after 30sec. 2) If user presses the notification to open the FullIntentActivity then the ringtone stops. 3) FullIntentActivity should get finished automatically after the rest time remaining from the 30 minus the time user clicked the notification. 4) Vibration should work along with the music. \Please fix those if you can to have a complete solution

Comment: @james04 Thanks, for my case I will get the call end push to end the ringing after 30 sec if the user didn't take the call. 2) for full Intent Activity u need another media player there to ring the ringtone(same case the fullintentActivity show in the lock screen).3)for automatically finish the FullIntentActivity you should write a timer there to close the Activity after 30 sec (for my case I will get call end push and also get call end from socket).

Comment: @james04 4) if you like to add vibration along with the music then just replace this if condition code with this if(!keyguardManager.isDeviceLocked()) {
    mediaPlayer.start();                         
 mvibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);            
    long[] pattern = {0, 250, 200, 250, 150, 150, 75,150, 75, 150};           
    mvibrator.vibrate(pattern,0);
 }

Comment: @Dinilps if i don't want to create notificationListenerService in my application then is there any option to trigger the above service on notification received, when my app is killed or background mode. How whatsapp done this scenario they never ask for notification access permission.

Comment: @EhsanUllah yes you can write all code in FirebaseMessagingService and Create a full-screen intent or display time-sensitive notification from there. so you don't need to create another foreground service for creating notifications.

Comment: Note that starting from SDK 31 (Android 12), we can't start activities from services or broadcast receivers which are started from the notification tap action. More info: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#notification-trampolines

Answer (score 3):

This is possible with **data messages from FCM**. You need setup following things:

1. Create a service extending `FirebaseMessagingService`. [Refer here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) in FCM docs. We will have to override `onMessageReceived()` in the service class.
2. Create a full screen intent or display time sensitive notification.[Refer here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive#create-high-priority-notification) in FCM docs. Show this notification in overridden `onMessageReceived()` in our service.
3. Now you have to find a way to send **data message from FCM**. Firebase console does not support this. Backend has to create a provision for this. [Refer here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#choosing-a-server-option).

Let me dive into more details.

**We have two different messages types in FCM**

1. **Notification message**: This is the common message type. This can be sent from notification composer in FCM console. This type of message will have properties named title, body etc. If we send notification message, `onMessageReceived()` will be invoked only if app is in foreground.
2. **Data message**: This cannot be sent from notification composer in FCM console. This type of message should have property data(payload). This is to be sent from server and it can of following format:

```
{
    "data":{
        "property1":"value1",
        "property2":42
    }
}
// Please note it should have data node.
```

If we send data message, `onMessageReceived()` will be invoked even if app is in backround or not in memory. That's what we want!

[Refer Data message in FCM Doc here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages)

**Let me revisit steps**

**Step #1**: This is the only service we have to create. we dont have to create any other foreground service. That's a different scenario.  Override `onMessageReceived()` to do the Step #2.

**Step #2**: Full screen intent or display time sensitive notification will show either a headup display notification as shown in the question or a whole activity to show incoming call. Show this notification in `onMessageReceived()` when we receive **data message** mentioned in Step #3.

**Step #3**: Reach out to server to send payload JSON I have shown above.

That's it!

Comment: @Dinil ps Thanks so much for this and  this Answer working for android 11 and below versions. not working on android 12 and higher. please help on this.